# My .remove() event isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've created a custom modal dialog that is added and removed from the screen when it is called. However, when I'm trying to remove it, the remove function doesn't seem to be working in certain circumstances.

This is the close function from the modal (triggered by clicking on the close button):

```
function modal_close() {
  $('.custom_block_page').fadeOut().remove();
  $(this).parent().fadeOut().remove();
};
```

This is how I call that function from the button inside the modal dialog:

```
MatchGame.closeWin = function() {
  $('.custom_modal_close').trigger('click');
  MatchGame.playGame();
};
```

If I just click the close button, the dialog is removed and everything works as expected. But when I trigger the close, the dialog fades to nothing, but remains in the body so it displays again the next time it is called.

Checking the console between I get:

```
$('.custom_block_page').length
1  // displayed the first time
$('.custom_block_page').length
0  // during the 2nd game (expected)
$('.custom_block_page').length
2  // displayed after the 2nd game; I expect this to be 1
```

I've tried putting a timeout on my playGame, but that didn't seem to help either.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What is `$('.custom_block_page')`

Comment: Please add more info, why do you expect `$('.custom_block_page').length` to be 1 for example, and what does it represent?

Comment: What is the behaviour without the .fadeout()s?

Comment: Depending on exactly how the function is called, `$(this)` will not point to what you think it points to.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan `$('.custom_block_page')` is the class that is created by the custom modal code.

Comment: @Elar, I expect that to be 1 because it should only be applied to the page 1 time, that is an existence test.

Comment: If anyone wants to see the full code it is on my GitHub page at: https://github.com/Chip-L/Match_Game. I warn you it is messy since I'm still learning.

Comment: `.remove()` can be many things. It cannot, though, be an `event`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you observe is due to `.fadeOut()`, which is implemented *asynchronously* in a whole series of later event threads.

Meanwhile, in the original event thread `.remove()`, subsequent statements, returning from the function and subsequent statements in the function's caller, ALL execute *synchronously* - well before `.fadeOut()` has completed.

The solution is to exploit `.promise()`, which will return a jQuery promise, from which you can chain `.then()` :

```
function modal_close() {
    return $('.custom_block_page').add($(this).parent()).fadeOut().promise().then(function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
};
```

In the caller, `.trigger()` returns jQuery but you now need to work with the returned promise, therefore use `.triggerHandler()`.

```
MatchGame.closeWin = function() {
    $('.custom_modal_close').triggerHandler('click').then(function() {
        MatchGame.playGame();
    });
};
```

**Edit:**

Code from `add_block_page()` and `add_popup_box()` can be safely rolled into `show_modal_box()` to make one larger function.

By doing so, you will benefit from being able to access the variables `$block_page`, `$pop_up`, `$close`, `$inner` from the close button's click handler.

```
function show_modal_box() {
    var $block_page = $('<div class="custom_block_page"></div>').appendTo('body'); // dark background
    var $pop_up = $('<div class="custom_modal_box"></div>').appendTo($block_page);
    var $close = $('<a href="#" class="custom_modal_close"></a>').appendTo($pop_up);
    var $inner = $('<div class="custom_inner_modal_box">loading...</div>').appendTo($pop_up);
    if(options.name != '') {
        $pop_up.attr('id', options.name);
    }

    // Add the content - if url, load the page otherwise use the text
    if (options.url != '') {
        $inner.load(options.url);
    } else {
        var innerHTML = '';
        if(options.title[0] === "<") { // assume formatting
            innerHTML += options.title;
        } else {
            innerHTML += '<h2>' + options.title + '</h2>';
        }
        if(options.description[0] === "<") {
            innerHTML += options.description;
        } else {
            innerHTML += '<p>' + options.description + '</p>';
        }
        $inner.html(innerHTML);
    }

    $close.click(function() {
        // for example
        return $pop_up.fadeOut().promise().then(function() {
            $block_page.remove();
        });
    });
    $(window).off('resize.popup').on('resize.popup', add_styles).trigger('resize.popup'); // prevent accumulation of resize handlers

    // checkNeedScroll();
    $pop_up.fadeIn();
}
```

**EDIT 2**

I think I have it!

In the `custom_modal_box` plugin, the code below causes a click handler to be appended to `this`:

```
    return this.click(function(e) {
        show_modal_box();
    });
```

That's fine if the plugin is invoked just once on any particular element however in this game's code it is invoked on the same element, `$('.win')`, every time a game is completed.

To prevent an accumulation of click handlers on `$('.win')`, change that code to :

```
    return this.off('click.popup').on('click.popup', function(e) {
        show_modal_box();
    });
```

Comment: I figured this was something to do with the asynchronous call but I couldn't figure out how to force them to be synchronous. I've never actually worked with promises before like this. However, this is still not working. I still am left with the remnant of the page.

Comment: My understanding is limited to what is in the question. The most obvious thing is that one or other of the two selectors is wrong - `$('.custom_block_page')` or `$(this).parent().`, or maybe some third selector needs to be added in.

Comment: I have added something that might help.

Comment: Thanks @Roamer-1888. This still isn't working. I was looking at the .promise() page in the JQuery API and it says this: _Note: The returned Promise is linked to a Deferred object stored on the .data() for an element. Since the.remove() method removes the element's data as well as the element itself, it will prevent any of the element's unresolved Promises from resolving. If it is necessary to remove an element from the DOM before its Promise is resolved, use .detach() instead and follow with .removeData() after resolution._ I don't understand what that means, can you help?

Comment: With `.triggerHandler('click')` in place, and providing that a close button actually exists, I can't see how `MatchGame.closeWin()` could fail to close the popup. To debug it, I would need to see the thing in action.

Comment: This should be published here https://chip-l.github.io/Match_Game/ with your recommended fixes. From what I've read I don't understand why it isn't working either. I have console logs showing that it is reaching the code and everything.

Comment: I rather think the custom_modal_box  code is working properly with or without my suggestions. The problem appears to be in the higher level game code. Some aspect of completed games remains active such that on completion of a subsequent game, custom_modal_boxes are created for that game AND all previous games.

Comment: I don't know how that is possible but I guess I'll go back and refactor the game to see if I can figure it out. I'll try going back to not using the plugin here and see if I can get it to work that way.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yes! That was the problem and it did fix it. I hadn't even thought about what adding multiple instances to the click handler would do. Thank you so much for the help!